# What type of 'field' for a time value

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

What field type would you use in a dataclass where the value provided is in a time format?

The JSON file I'm parsing returns a value like this: `2.00:00:15.0830000`

In a class like this below, what type should I set?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Values:
    duration: ???
```

`date` type seems not to be on the list.

The reason I require a non-`str` here is to calculate if the value is older than x days/hours then do something.

Comment: If you want a non-`str` you should _parse_ it, use e.g. `datetime`.

Comment: `dataclass` doesn't convert things for you. It declares what they already are. Passing a string value to a non-`str` dataclass field doesn't do any actual work. It just lies to you and then lets things fail awkwardly later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can save it as a `str` (string), and then have a member function to convert it to decimal hours, mins, etc. In that case, maybe a `dataclass` is not appropriate (dataclasses tend to only hold data).

Alternatively, you may want to explore the package [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html), with its own datetime class and member functions.